# Finding the child table for a cascading delete

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have just deleted a few records from a table. The message tab lists the "affected row count x" twice, I assume, because there has been the same number of records deleted for a child table. I am new to this database and there is no documentation.

Is there an easy way to find the child table?

Comment: How many statements did you run?  Was it one statement or multiple statements?  \

Comment: It was a single statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the SQL Server Management Studio you can right click on the Table and click on "View Dependencies". When you select "Objects that depend on [TableName]" you will get a list. It can be quite big, if there are a lot of Stored procedures and functions. You will be able to spot the tables very easy, as they have a distinctive "table" icon.

However, if you can't use SSMS, then you will need to run script. This script will list all Foreign keys with child and parent tables:

```
SELECT     db_name() AS CONSTRAINT_CATALOG, user_name(c_obj.uid) AS CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA, c_obj.name AS CONSTRAINT_NAME, db_name() 
                      AS TABLE_CATALOG, user_name(t_obj.uid) AS TABLE_SCHEMA, t_obj.name AS TABLE_NAME, 
                      CASE c_obj.xtype WHEN 'C' THEN 'CHECK' WHEN 'UQ' THEN 'UNIQUE' WHEN 'PK' THEN 'PRIMARY KEY' WHEN 'F' THEN 'FOREIGN KEY' END AS CONSTRAINT_TYPE,
                       'NO' AS IS_DEFERRABLE, 'NO' AS INITIALLY_DEFERRED,
mt_obj.name AS ParentTable
FROM         sysobjects c_obj, sysobjects t_obj, sysforeignkeys sf, sysobjects mt_obj 
WHERE     permissions(t_obj.id) != 0 AND t_obj.id = c_obj.parent_obj AND c_obj.xtype IN ('F')
AND sf.constid = c_obj.id AND sf.rkeyid = mt_obj.id
```

BTW, do not rule out the possibility of a TRIGGER

Comment: Cha, thank you very much. I am using the SSMS and this should have been obvious. When I get a moment I will use your script. When you say "do not rule out the possibility of a TRIGGER' does this mean they will have their own count for "affected row count"?  Thanks John!